# What is the difference between Mapbox GL JS and Cesium?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, google-earth-plugin

Google earth API has been abolished.
It seems that the kml file used in Google earth can be used in Cesium. Can it be used in MapBox GL JS?
Cesium does not have complete 3D building information.
MapBox GL JS has prepared 3D building information, but I don't know if it can be freely developed for in-house Web applications.

Answer (score 3):

Cesium and Mapbox-GL-JS are both Javascript libraries for displaying maps using WebGL. Other than that they're extremely different. Cesium supports a globe view, 3D tiles, full 3D, textured meshes and tons of other things. Mapbox-GL-JS supports 2.5D (that is, a 2D shape with height), with limited support for compositing true 3D objects using other libraries such as Three.JS.

> Cesium does not have complete 3D building information. MapBox GL JS has prepared 3D building information

Cesium and Mapbox-GL-JS are just rendering engines. However, Mapbox.com provides basemaps that contain building data.

Comment: 3D objects are displayed on google earth using kml files.
Is it possible to display on Map box GL JS using this kml file?

Comment: You can upload KML files to Mapbox and then display them as vector tiles.